# GKAchievement.loadAchievements is always returning an empty array

Tags: swift, game-center, achievements

`GKAchievement.loadAchievements` is always returning an empty array. It's authenticated with the local player, and `GKAchievement.report` works perfectly. I'm able to see the unlocked achievement in the Game Center.

Auth

```
func authPlayer(){
        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.local
        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
            (view,error) in
            if view != nil {
                self.present(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                print(GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated)
            }
        }
    }
```

Loading achievements

```
static func loadAchievements() {
        GKAchievement.loadAchievements(completionHandler: { achievements, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to load achievments", error as Any)
                return
            }
            for achievement in achievements! { // this is always an empty array
                let characterType = self.achievements[achievement.identifier]
                
                if characterType != nil  && achievement.isCompleted {
                    self.saveCharacterUnlock(character: .rabbit, type: characterType!)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Saving an achievement

```
static private func saveCharacterAchievement(type: Int) {
        let achievementName = achievements.first(where: { key, value in return value == type })?.key
        guard achievementName != nil else {
            return
        }
        let achievement = GKAchievement.init(identifier: achievementName!)
        achievement.percentComplete = 100
        GKAchievement.report([achievement], withCompletionHandler: {
            error in
            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to save achievement", error as Any)
            }
        })
    }
```